# JQuery UI: moving list items between multiple unordered lists

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to sort multiple and multilevel unordered lists.

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
            }).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list">
    <ul id="list1" class="connectedSortable">
        <li title='1'>Foo1</li>
        <li title='2'>Foo2
            <ul id="list3" class="connectedSortable">
                <li title='3'>FooBar1</li>
                <li title='4'>FooBar2</li>
                <li title='5'>FooBar3</li>
                <li title='6'>FooBar4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li title='7'>Foo3</li>
        <li title='8'>Foo4</li>
        <li title='9'>Foo5</li>
        <li title='10'>Foo6</li>
        <li title='11'>Foo7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li title='12'>Bar1</li>
        <li title='13'>Bar2</li>
        <li title='14'>Bar3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need also two informations to be accessible at the time when I sort the list items: an id of the parent element - stored on the parent elements title (0 if doesnt has a parent element) and the id of the list (like list1 and list2 - not list3).
How would you implement this?
Any information is welcome.

PS: I am quite new in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7NH4/) with the solution. The main idea is to use the `containment` property for `sortable` to tell every list to remain within itself.